# Pytesseract loop error

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I'm trying to loop pytesseract code to convert multiple images(18) into strings and name the output in sequece. tried to rearrange and replace the loop position more errors accur.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

src_path = "/home/pi/Desktop/"

def get_string(img_path):

    for n in range(0,18):

        n=n+1

        img = cv2.imread(img_path)

        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
        img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
        img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

        cv2.imwrite(src_path + "removed_noise"+ n +".png",img)
        cv2.imwrite(src_path +"thres"+ n +".png", img)

        result = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(src_path + "thres"+ n +".png"))

    return result

print (get_string(src_path +"sample"+ str(n) +".jpeg"))
print ("------ Done -------")
```

it returns an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/imagetostring.py", line 29, in <module>
    print (get_string(src_path +"sample"+ str(n) +".jpeg"))
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

`n` is a [local variable](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) of the `get_string` function. With your indentation, the `print` statement is outside this function, so the variable is out of scope, hence the error.

Simple code to explain scopes of local variables:

```
def someFunction(N):
    print(myLocal) # ERROR: myLocal not defined yet.
    for myLocal in range(1,N):
        print(myLocal) # OK
    print(myLocal) # OK

print(myLocal) # ERROR (your case): myLocal can't be accessed outside someFunction.
               # It doesn't even exist while someFunction is not being executed.
```

Comment: posted the modified code. no output no error, would you please check it.

Comment: @sanqar Stackoverflow is a question & answer site. This question was about a `NameError`, and I hope I was able to provide an helpful answer. If you have a different problem with a different code, you should post a different question. Before that, I would suggest that you spend some time on a Python tutorial/book to grasp the basics of the language.